# javascript how can i modify if - else if - else code

Tags: javascript

This is a code i try to modify. the case is: when u click on a button (it can have 3 textes), it switches. and when you click again you can get only 2 different texts on it. and now you are not able to change to the previous state

```js
let list = document.querySelector('.todo-list');
let input = document.querySelector('.todo-input');
let form = document.querySelector('.todo-form');
let priority = document.querySelector('.todo-priority');

const isImportant = () => {
  return priority.classList.contains('is-important');
}

priority.onclick = function() {
  priority.classList.toggle('is-important');
  if (isImportant()) {
    priority.textContent = 'Задача на один день';
  } else {
    priority.textContent = 'Повседневная и посторяющаяся задача (будет автоматически добавлена в каждый день недели)';
  }
};

form.onsubmit = function(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  const newTask = document.createElement('li');
  newTask.textContent = input.value;
  if (isImportant()) {
    newTask.classList.add('is-important');
  }
  list.append(newTask);

  input.value = '';
};
```

```html
<h1 class="heading">Список задач</h1>

<ol class="todo-list">
  <li>Договориться о встрече</li>
  <li class="is-important">Поесть</li>
</ol>

<form class="todo-form" action="https://echo.htmlacademy.ru/courses" method="post">
  <label class="input-label" for="todo-input">Добавьте задачу</label>
  <input type="text" class="todo-input" id="todo-input" required>
  <button type="button" class="todo-priority is-important">Важная задача</button>
  <button type="submit" class="todo-add">Добавить в список</button>
</form>

<script src="ADDING.js"></script>
```

this is what i tried to do but the button stopped working completely 0-0

```js
let list = document.querySelector('.todo-list');
let input = document.querySelector('.todo-input');
let form = document.querySelector('.todo-form');
let priority = document.querySelector('.todo-priority');
flag = False;
const isImportant = () => {
  return priority.classList.contains('is-important');
}

priority.onclick = function() {
  priority.classList.toggle('is-important');
  if (isImportant() && flag == False) {
    priority.textContent = 'Задача на один день';
    flag = True;
    priority.classList.toggle('is-important');
  } else if (isImportant() && flag) {
    priority.textContent = 'Важная задача';
    flag = False;
    isImportant = False
  } else {
    priority.textContent = 'Повторяющаяся задача';
  }
};

form.onsubmit = function(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  const newTask = document.createElement('li');
  newTask.textContent = input.value;
  if (isImportant()) {
    newTask.classList.add('is-important');
  }
  list.append(newTask);

  input.value = '';
};
```

```html
<h1 class="heading">Список задач</h1>

<ol class="todo-list">
  <li>Договориться о встрече</li>
  <li class="is-important">Поесть</li>
</ol>

<form class="todo-form" action="https://echo.htmlacademy.ru/courses" method="post">
  <label class="input-label" for="todo-input">Добавьте задачу</label>
  <input type="text" class="todo-input" id="todo-input" required>
  <button type="button" class="todo-priority is-important">Важная задача</button>
  <button type="submit" class="todo-add">Добавить в список</button>
</form>

<script src="ADDING.js"></script>
```

Comment: I made snippets. There is an obvious error in the second one. JavaScript is case sensitive

Comment: Also you can test like this: `if (isImportant() && !flag)` instead of `... flag== false`

Comment: `isImportant = False` is a problem. You're replacing the function with a regular variable, so you'll get an error the next time you click.

Comment: you could use `isImportant = () => false` to replace it with a function that always returns `false`.

Comment: And as the above comment alludes, `False` must be `false` (are you a Python programmer?).

Comment: yeah, i am. that's why i struggle so much with js now